# Dynamical Java spreadsheet/table

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable

I am facing the task of making a dynamical spreadsheet in Java that has a grid of cells and does operations between between them. I have to "put" all my cells in some kind of container and get an integer index for every cell. I could only think about an array into an array or maybe a JTable. I have to remind that later on I will have to implement this into an Android App. Please help me.

I tried something like this (it's totally wrong):

```
public class 
BaseCell {

public double value;
int i=0,j=0;
int row=20, column=5;


BaseCell[] PrimaryCellArray = new BaseCell[i];
    for (i=0; i<column; i++){
        BaseCell[] SecondaryCellArray = new BaseCell[j];
        SecondaryCellArray.addObj();
    } PrimaryBaseCell.addObj.S
    //then add the secondary cell to primary cell

}
}
```

Comment: "Plese help me with this because is very important for me." as is any other question.

Comment: @user3063468 which IDE you are using??

Comment: @user3063468 you can use netbeans for design swing gui from the front end.

Comment: I am using Eclipse with Android SDK. i Got to the point that i'm thinking that the Maps implementation is pretty ok but i don't know how how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might misunderstand the question, but IMO List would be the best would be to use one of list types.

```
int rows = 20, cols = 10;
List myList = new Lise();
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
   BaseCell[] secondaryCellArray = new BaseCell[cols];
   myList.add(secondaryCellArray);
}
```

to get acces to some cell, call the row you need with `myList.get(rowNum)`, it will return you variable of that type you're set there before

Comment: Looks like a good point,but what if i would do this in a TreeMap with <Index, BaseCell>, i think this way is easier to get what i want. What do you think?

Comment: @user3063468 so what's the problem? You take 'BaseCell[] secondaryCellArray' and out it into your TreeMap with its key. Works same as with List, only difference is in method and that you need to add key value for TreeMap